# How to wrap a series of icons after three

Tags: html, css

I have downloaded a bootstrap theme:

Info: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/stylish-portfolio

Demo: http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-stylish-portfolio

On the page 'our services', it shows 4 circles with font-awesome icons.  I have added a 2 more circles and font-awesome icons to that.  But i only added 2... So on the page, its kinda awkward, a whole line of circles and icons, then a smaller line of just 2 right under the other circles/icons.. I want their to be 3 on each line and to be centered.

I looked through the css code, but I can't find anything. Here is the code

```
.service-item {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/* Callout */

.callout {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(../img/callout.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}





<!-- Services -->
<!-- The circle icons use Font Awesome's stacked icon classes. For more information, visit http://fontawesome.io/examples/ -->
<section id="services" class="services bg-primary">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                <h2>Our Services</h2>
                <hr class="small">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="service-item">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                        </span>
                            <h4>
                                <strong>Service Name</strong>
                            </h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="service-item">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-compass fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                        </span>
                            <h4>
                                <strong>Service Name</strong>
                            </h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="service-item">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-flask fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                        </span>
                            <h4>
                                <strong>Service Name</strong>
                            </h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="service-item">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-shield fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                        </span>
                            <h4>
                                <strong>Service Name</strong>
                            </h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row (nested) -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-10 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</section>
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML as well so we can evaluate?

Comment: Please make a complete example, not just the css. Preferably a snippet.

Comment: Just posted the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Columns add up to 12 so 4 columns at md-3 you want 6 columns at md-4.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the document you'll see this common Bootstrap markup structure:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

This results in the icons being arranged 2 to a row for mobile, and 4 to a row at larger screen sizes. You'll need to modify the template files per the Bootstrap grid docs to this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

This would result in each icon section taking one-third of the width of the row, and then they'd wrap to a new line.

You could also beat it into submission with CSS overrides, but I wouldn't recommend it.